# Execute python from Symfony Process fails

Tags: php, python, linux, symfony

I am executing a simple `python -v` from:

```
$process = new Process(['python -v']);
$process->run();

try {
      if (!$process->isSuccessful()) 
      {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
      }
     }
      catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
     }
```

but I get the exception:

```
The command "'python -v'" failed.  Exit Code: 127(Command not found)  Working directory: /var/www/symfony/symfony/public  Output: ================   Error Output: ================ sh: 1: exec: python -v: not found
```

If I run the same command from the shell all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$process = new Process(['phyton -v']);
```

to

```
$process = new Process(['phyton',  '-v']);
```

Ref. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage

Comment: Did you mean `python` instead of `phyton`?